# How to bypass the new 3rd party cookie issue with google calendar

Tags: cookies, google-api

I have a simple fetch to a public google calendar to access the events listed:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getPublicCalendarEvents() {
    const API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    const calendarID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CALENDAR_ID
    const calendarUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarID}/events?key=${API_KEY}`;

    const events = axios.get(calendarUrl, { withCredentials: false });
    console.log(events);
    return events
    
  }
```

But I get breaking issues in the console warning about the 3rd party cookies issue.

I've solved this in other areas, such as youtube ([www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/etc...](http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/etc...)) but is there a similar simple workaround for my google calendar api?